How to render glyph from a field from vtkArrayCalculator
I am trying to visualize wake field of a propeller.
the field data is written in Tecplot format and have 3 scalar; u, v, w.
After loading with vtkTecplotReader, I would like to visualize v, w field with glyph after making vector field through vtkArrayCalculator.
my code goes as follows:
vtkTecplotReader reader = new vtkTecplotReader();
reader.SetFileName("wake.dat");
reader.Update();

vtkMultiBlockDataSet multiBDS = new vtkMultiBlockDataSet();
multiBDS = reader.GetOutput();

// vector glyph
vtkArrayCalculator calculator = new vtkArrayCalculator();
for (uint i = 0; i < multiBDS.GetNumberOfBlocks(); i++)
{
    vtkPointSet block;
    if (multiBDS.GetBlock(i).IsA("vtkStructuredGrid") == 1)
    {
        block = multiBDS.GetBlock(i) as vtkStructuredGrid;
    }
    else
    {
        block = multiBDS.GetBlock(i) as vtkUnstructuredGrid;
    }
    calculator.AddInputData(block);
}

calculator.AddScalarArrayName("u", 0);
calculator.AddScalarArrayName("v", 0);
calculator.AddScalarArrayName("w", 0);
calculator.SetFunction("jHat*v + kHat*w");
calculator.SetResultArrayName("wake");
calculator.Update();

vtkGlyph2D glyph2D = new vtkGlyph2D();
glyph2D.SetSourceConnection(calculator.GetOutputPort());
glyph2D.Update();

vtkPolyDataMapper glyph2DMapper = new vtkPolyDataMapper();
glyph2DMapper.SetInputConnection(glyph2D.GetOutputPort());
glyph2DMapper.Update();

vtkActor glyph2DActor = new vtkActor();
glyph2DActor.SetMapper(glyph2DMapper);
glyph2DActor.GetProperty().SetColor(0, 0, 0);


But with this code, I got the following warning
vtkDemandDrivenPipeline:677    ERR| vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0000024358F719B0): Input port 0 of algorithm vtkGlyph2D (0000024358F22C10) has 0 connections but is not optional

Any comments and advice would be grateful.

The glyph needs 2 "inputs":

the classical vtk "Input", i.e. the data containing the vector field in your case
and the "Source", i.e. the geometry to be displayed at each point of the inputs.

Your script should use SetInputConnection instead of SetSourceConnection with the calculator and then add a SetSourceConnection with a vtkArrowSource (for instance).
See this example: https://examples.vtk.org/site/Cxx/Visualization/VectorField/
